# Cordova Show content on the lock screen android

Tags: cordova, android-activity, ionic-framework, lockscreen, android-windowmanager

I want to show some interactive content on the lock screen. I already have a listener which gets fired when power button is pressed to turn the screen on, I just don't know how to display a dismissable webview on the lock screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

locking
(optional)
boolean 
Whether to lock scrolling in one direction at a time. Useful to set to false when zoomed in or scrolling in two directions. Default true.
than you can show your can interactive content on the lock screen.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you, if I was not clear enough for you, I want to show some content on the lock screen (where a pattern to unlock is shown when the screen is locked, on top of that)